# Grub boot from Windows iso

Tags: grub2, windows-10, iso

Hello i want grub to boot Windows .
I have a Windows ISO in my Linux Filesystem .
I have No USB Ports .
Uefi bios

Comment: Without a USB port, you cannot install windows alongside Linux. You have to have a Windows bootable USB. 
Another option could be a Virtual Machine to install Windows inside Linux. Use the VirtualBox or GNOME Boxes app to create a Windows virtual machine and use it inside Linux.

Comment: My machine ist to Week to have a virtual machine

Comment: Isnt it possible to create a Partition with an unzipped ISO File , and Boot from it ?

Comment: You can do that on windows using Wubi (Windows-based Ubuntu Installer) software. So, search for any Linux-based Windows Installer if there is any. But I think it would be risky as it might break any partition.

Comment: What kind of PC do you have and how did you install Ubuntu on the machine?

Comment: Well i installed Ubuntu via USB , but now the USB ports are all. Dead.

Comment: Dead USB ports do show up in google, might be easier to try to fix them first, unless it is a hardware problem.  Seems like ubuntu is not seeing them more than they are broken.

Comment: One could Work , but there are No drivers for my Laptop for Linux
I have a e200ha . The Internet says there are issiues with this when installing Linux https://wiki.debian.org/InstallingDebianOn/Asus/E200HA